# The Last Challenge

Tags: cipher, story

This question is a continuation of [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107615/the-thiefs-341-name), and you might want to read it if you haven't already.

'Another code-name,' I think. 'There's no way that's his real name'. Nonetheless, I type in 'ANONYMOUS' and the other monitors immediately blank out. There is no light left in the room except the light of the last monitor. It shows a blank screen. The white resembles my face as my heart pounds at I stare at the screen, afraid of what comes next.

Suddenly, another message comes on the screen, just like last time, as if it is being typed while I try to restrain myself from shaking the screen to make the words appear faster.

'Nice job! My last victim, ahem, test subject was only able to make it so far. Of course, I won't give up so easily. I have one last and *FINAL* test. If you pass this, I will reveal why I made you do all this...'

The screen changed to some sequences of letters. And after that, another place to input. Why, oh-why did I ever apply for a job like this??

1st sequence :

> Vwccx+V1qS/aNMjfDOmGsYjfEZ0aOU6sLS956nmwytE=

2nd sequence :

> +HenDyfgwgjaL8S7c12X/g==

3rd sequence :

> DPLOnlzReUnq6CLBQhYC/w==

Hint 1:

> Another day, anoTher puzzle, another piece from the tray,
>  Another clue, another hint, another dead-end to gRey.
>  This is a chance that I give You,
>  Another chAnce to solve this puzzle true.
>  The clock’s ticking, it sounds from afar likE ringing,
>  That’S the time a-leaving you, chance to solve this puzzle true.

Hint 2:

> Try using the 128, 192 and the 256 ones.

Comment: I'm going to assume that by now our hero is the newest victim.

Comment: @amquack, he will be, lest you can solve the puzzle by this evening.......